# Why the query didn't update after click at the update button?

Tags: php, mysql

From my previous post (duplicated one - [How to edit & update in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746381/how-to-edit-update-in-php?noredirect=1#comment98169544_55746381))

**Problem**

After I click at the update button (in front.php), the session message is shown but the query didn't update.

**What I have tried so far**

In `edit&update.php`, `count()` is not available after PHP 7.0+.

So I changed into `is_countable()` but I don't know it is an equivalent/compatible function to `count()` or not.

**Notes**

For `edit&update.php`, I will change into the prepared statement later if the query is able to be updated after clicking at the update button.

There is no warning or notice while running the code but the query didn't update after clicking at the update button.

**front.php**

```
<html>
<?php 
require_once 'edit&update.php';
include 'connection.php';
?>
<body>
<!--ID (hidden)-->
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><!--ID-->
<!--Category-->
<label>Category</label>:
<select name="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>">
       <option value="0">(Please any type below)</option>
       <option value="A">A</option>
       <option value="D">D</option>
       <option value="M">M</option>
       <option value="S">S</option>
       <option value="T">T</option>
       <option value="Tr">Tr</option>
       <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<!--URL-->
<label>URL</label>:
<input type="url" name="url" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" placeholder="URL (www.)" required>
<!--Issued date-->
<label>Issued date:</label><br>
<input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" value="<?php echo $datetime; ?>" required>
<!--Latitude-->
<label>Latitude</label>:
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $lat; ?>" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude">
<!--Longitude-->
<label>Longitude</label>:&nbsp
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $lng; ?>" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude">

<div class="row" style="padding: 10px">
    <div class="col">
        <?php if($update == true):
        ?>
        <button type="submit" name="Update">Update</button>
        <?php else: ?>
        <button type="submit" name="Save">Save</button>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit&update.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

      //Default
      $id=0;
      $update = false;
      $category = '';
      $url = '';
      $datetime = '';
      $lat = '';
      $lng = '';

if (isset($_GET['id']))
      {
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          $update = true;
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_id=$id";
          $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

          if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
          {
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
              $category = $row['crimenews_cat'];
              $url = $row['crimenews_url'];
              $datetime = $row['crimenews_datetime'];
              $lat = $row['crimenews_locationLat'];
              $lng = $row['crimenews_locationLong'];
          }
      }
  if (isset($_POST['Update']))
      {
          $id = $_POST['id'];
          $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['category']);
          $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url']);
          $datetime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['datetime']);
          $lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lat']);
          $lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lng']);

          $conn->query("UPDATE crimenews SET crimenews_cat='$category', crimenews_url='$url', crimenews_datetime='$datetime', crimenews_locationLat='$lat', crimenews_locationLong='$lng' WHERE crimenews_id=$id");

          $_SESSION['message'] = "This news has updated";
          $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "warning";

          header('location: front.php');
        }
```

Comment: The way is simple: you echo value to debug. or add [error_reporting(~0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);] at top file php to view error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to `count` the result of a call to [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) at all (it's a `mysqli_result` object, not an array). Instead, to find out how many rows were returned by the query, check the value of [`mysqli_num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) i.e. change

```
if (is_countable($query)==1)
```

to

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
```

You also need to change

```
$row = $sel->fetch_array();
```

to

```
$row = $query->fetch_array();
```

as `$query` is the name of your result object, not `$sel`.

Based on the results of your query, and the update code following, it seems what you really want is this:

```
$category = $row['crime_cat'];
$url = $row['crimenews_url'];
$datetime = $row['crimenews_datetime'];
$lat = $row['crimenews_locationLat'];
$lng = $row['crimenews_locationLong'];
```

Comment: Well, I already tried but there are syntax errors Notice: Undefined index: category/url/datetime/lat/lng

Comment: @OSan on what line?

Comment: Everything within ‘if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==1)’ statement

Comment: Ok, I already edited but the undefined index errors are still shown up.

Comment: @OSan what do you get if you `print_r($row);` after the `$row = $query->fetch_array();`?

Comment: This is my latest (dummy) query in MySQL server `Array ( [0] => 26 [crimenews_id] => 26 [1] => Murder [crimenews_cat] => Murder [2] => https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2019/04/18/londonderry-riots-woman-dies-shots-fired-petrol-bombs-thrown/ [crimenews_url] => https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2019/04/18/londonderry-riots-woman-dies-shots-fired-petrol-bombs-thrown/ [3] => 2019-04-19 19:35:00 [crimenews_datetime] => 2019-04-19 19:35:00 [4] => 54.7877149 [crimenews_locationLat] => 54.7877149 [5] => -6.4923140 [crimenews_locationLong] => -6.4923140 ) `

Comment: Well, there are no category/url/datetime/lat/lng  entries in that array, so it's no surprise you are getting undefined index errors...

Comment: Then, what should I do?

Comment: @OSan see my edit. You are not using the correct column names.

Comment: There is no syntax error now but the query didn't get updated after clicking at `update` button

Comment: Now you need to debug the update query. Change that line to `$conn->query("UPDATE crimenews SET crime_cat='$category', crimenews_url='$url', crimenews_datetime='$datetime', crimenews_locationLat='$lat', crimenews_locationLong='$lng' WHERE crimenews_id=$id") or die($conn->error);`