# How to convert this part of code into prepared statement in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

From my previous post ([Why the query didn't update after click at the update button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755679/why-the-query-didnt-update-after-click-at-the-update-button/55755715?noredirect=1#comment98198940_55755715))

**Statement**

How to convert the part of code into the prepared statement?

**edit.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
      {
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          $update = true;
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_id=$id";
          $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1)
          {
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
              $category = $row['crimenews_cat'];
              $url = $row['crimenews_url'];
              $datetime = $row['crimenews_datetime'];
              $lat = $row['crimenews_locationLat'];
              $lng = $row['crimenews_locationLong'];
          }
      }
```

More codes have already provided in the given link above.

Comment: One line at a time would be my prefered method, referencing the PHP manual Often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// while testing add
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $update = true;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $res = $stmt->get_result();

    if($res->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // fetch_assoc() returns just an assoc array and not the numeric array as well
        $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

        $category = $row['crimenews_cat'];
        $url = $row['crimenews_url'];
        $datetime = $row['crimenews_datetime'];
        $lat = $row['crimenews_locationLat'];
        $lng = $row['crimenews_locationLong'];
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement.    
2. Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Comment: Did you change the query to use a `?` instead of `$id`

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Comment: Fixed a couple of typos, sorry