# How to use is_countable to count if there is a row in the tbl that would equal to it?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following a tutorial that will display the entire record of a person to input text boxes from table rows upon hitting the button and every thing seems okay and working however the if (count($result)==1) is showing Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable tho it's working

Upon searching I've read that this count() already been an issue before with php 7.2 version but with php 7.3 they it was fixed by coming up with the is_countable. However as I tried putting is_countable the code isn't working.

with count() it is working but showing an error
with is_countable it is not working

The version of my php is 7.3.3

How to use is_countable properly in php 7.3.3?

#### count() it is working returning tbl row values on textboxes but showing an error - Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

```
if (count($result)==1) {
   #code
 }
```

#### is_countable it is not working totally

```
if (is_countable($result)==1) {
  #code
 }
```

I expect to see the values of rows from tbl to input textboxes

like the

```
$rlname = $row['lname'];
```

to show to

```
<input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php echo $rlname ?>">
```

Comment: What is `$result`?

Comment: You can use `mysqli_num_rows` if you are using MYSQLi - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysqli_num_rows.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the query didn't update after click at the update button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755679/why-the-query-didnt-update-after-click-at-the-update-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the query didn't update after click at the update button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755679/why-the-query-didnt-update-after-click-at-the-update-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much hemnath mouli, Nick and Mr Shunz it is now working after changing the

```
if (is_countable($result)==1) {
  $row = $result->fetch_array();
 }
```

to

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
```